# Python import no module

Tags: python, python-import

Another user successfully imports `xml`. When I try to `import xml`, Python can't find the module. Why is that?

My traceback:

```
>>> import xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xml.py", line 13, in <module>
    from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
ImportError: No module named etree
```

This is on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You have a local module named `xml.py`; this *masks* the built-in package.

You'll have to rename that package; it is importing *itself* otherwise.